# Set minimum height of table view cell?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, constraints

I have a **UITableView**,In this table i have created as custom cell with image & label.I have given label leading,trailing,top,bottom.I want to set the size of label to increase according to text which is happening.I have used **UITableAutomaticDimension** & **EstimatedRowHeight**.Now i want to set minimum height of cell equal to height of image.Now if text is very less in label then height of image is decreased.Now i want to keep height cell minimum as image height & increase it when there is more text.Please help how can i do it?

[image]

Comment: try setting the height constraint of label as : greater than or equal to imageViews height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the view you shared i would suggest the following constraints.

1. Top of UIImageView to top of your cell.
2. Left of UIImageView top left of your cell.
3. Width and Height constraints of your UIImageView.
4. Bottom of UIImageView to the bottom of your cell which will be greater than or equal to.
5. Right of your UIImageView to Left of your UILabel.
6. Top of your UILabel to top of your cell.
7. Right of your UILabel to right of your cell.
8. Bottom of your UILabel to bottom of your cell.

Adding these constraints should solve your problems.

Comment: Does not work.If the content of label is increased then height of image is also increased

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your ui for better understanding of your problem?

Comment: I have edited my answer and have suggested some constraints try adding them and see if this helps.